# How to exchange JComboBox items with another one?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, jcombobox

I'm trying to make a currency converter program, and I want JComboBox items to get replaced from the other JComboBox [when I hit the convert button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/em24b.png)

I know the mistake is to try and convert String to integer, but I see no other way to set JComboBox's contents.

[A screenshot from NetBeans with my results in case the code is hard to understand.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPHTH.png)

Below is the code of jButton:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
                try {
              for(int a = 0; a < 4; a++){
                String box2 = (currency2.getItemAt(a));
            System.out.println("List items b4 conversion, JComboBox1: "+ currency1.getItemAt(a));
            System.out.println("List items b4 conversion, JComboBox2: "+ box2+"\n");
            System.out.println("--End of first 2 items--");
System.out.println("JComboBox2 after conv" +currency1.getItemAt(Integer.parseInt(box2)));
                }

                    }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                        System.out.println("error");
                }    
    }
```

Here's what it prints:

```
List items b4 conversion, JComboBox1: EUR
List items b4 conversion, JComboBox2: ALL

--End of first 2 items--
error
```

Meanwhile, when I remove: `System.out.println("JComboBox2 after conv" +currency1.getItemAt(Integer.parseInt(box2)))`,it prints all items of 2 JComboBoxes as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String txt1 = (String) JComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
    String txt2 = (String) JComboBox2.getSelectedItem();
    jComboBox1.setSelectedItem(txt2);
    jComboBox2.setSelectedItem(txt1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much I can't believe it was that easy! (*laughing in embarrassment*)

Comment: No problem, it happens :)